# How do I add an entry to a category progammatically in an add-on?

Tags: add-on-development, categories

I have a site that uses ChannelForms for users to add entries to a channel. These entries need to be categorised, but I can't rely on users to pick the right category as this depends on data they enter in other fields in the form, which isn't known until the form is submitted.

How can I set the category programmatically according to known rules using an add-on on the ChannelForm return page in the same way that [yo_status_tools](https://github.com/ChrisLTD/yo_status_tools) does for entry statuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way ExpressionEngine handle's categories is in the exp_category_posts table. In order to assign an entry to a category, simply insert the new entry id into the entry_id column and the associated category id in the cat_id table.

Here is an example of my category_post table

[image]